# Unable to install Simon

Tags: software-installation, simon

I'm trying to install Simon using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grasch-simon-listens/simon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simon
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 simon : Depends: libattica0 but it is not installable
```

How can I install required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the builds present in the **ppa:grasch-simon-listens/simon** there is a build for  Ubuntu version 12.04 LTS.

More recent Ubuntu version (>= 14.04 LTS) will have [**simon**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/simon) [image: Install banshee] available from the universe repository.

Alternatively we can always [install software from the source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) available for download from the [Simon KDE Project](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/accessibility/simon/repository) or from it's [Launchpad branch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simon).

Comment: I have that installed already.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 12.04 Try this after you added the PPA:

Open a terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
mkdir -p simon/DEBIAN
wget https://launchpad.net/~grasch-simon-listens/+archive/simon/+files/simon_0.3.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb
dpkg -e simon_0.3.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb simon/DEBIAN
dpkg -x simon_0.3.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb simon/ 
gedit simon/DEBIAN/control
```

In GEDIT, search for `libattica0` and change it to `libattica0.3`

Save and close gedit

Type in terminal:

```
dpkg -b ./simon simon_0.3.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi simon_0.3.0-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

Simon should install now...

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 13.04 Simon will be in repos: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=simon&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Answer (score -1):

in ubuntu package currently being released. I simply typed.

sudo apt-get install simon

Comment: -1 OP already tried to install that package and it didn't work.